# Merging tuples with identical items within a tuple in Python

Tags: python, tuples

I realize this is a basic question but I cannot get this to work.
I have the following tuple:

```
t = (('apple', 'banana'), ('apple', 'carrot'), ('banana', 'carrot'))
```

I want the first item within every tuple in `t` to be unique, and to merge the second item of every duplicate together into a dictionary.

```
t = {('apple': 'banana', 'carrot'), ('banana': 'carrot')}
```

Not surprisingly, this doesn't work:

```
t = dict(zip(set(t[0]),t[1]))
```

This is the result:

```
{'apple': 'apple', 'banana': 'carrot'}
```

Comment: Are you sure you really need nested tuple instead of dictionary here?

Comment: I suppose dictionary would be preferable, you're right

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think, you should use a `dict` here (or rather a `defaultdict`). Where `key` of the `dict` would be the first element of your inner tuples - `tup[0]`.

This is what you want:

```
>>> t = (('apple', 'banana'), ('apple', 'carrot'), ('banana', 'carrot'))
>>>
>>> from collections import defaultdict
>>> 
>>> temp_dict = defaultdict(tuple)
>>> 
>>> for tup in t:
        temp_dict[tup[0]] += tup[1:]  


>>> temp_dict
defaultdict(<type 'tuple'>, {'apple': ('banana', 'carrot'), 'banana': ('carrot',)})

>>> {key:value for key, value in temp_dict.items()}
{'apple': ('banana', 'carrot'), 'banana': ('carrot',)}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a complete solution (Edit: **Now** *Python 3 compatible*):

```
import functools
t = (('apple', 'banana'), ('apple', 'carrot'), ('banana', 'carrot'))

def insert(d,k,v):
        d[k] = (v,) if k not in d else d[k]+(v,)
        return d

z = functools.reduce(lambda d,ti: insert(d,*ti),t,{})

def flat(tpl):
        return sum([(x,) if not isinstance(x,tuple) else x for x in tpl],())

result = [flat(x) for x in z.items()]
```

Yields :

`[('apple', 'banana', 'carrot'), ('banana', 'carrot')]`

Comment: Based on Rohit's recommendation, I feel that a dictionary would be preferable. This solution worked, but I guess a tuple is not what I'm looking for. Thanks Cris!

Comment: Note that anonymous tuple arguments (like your `(k,v)` in `insert`) are no longer allowed in Python 3. You'll either need to use two separate arguments `k` and `v` or match a single name for the combined tuple, then unpack manually. Also, you can simplify the `else` case to `d[k]+(v,)` (no need to use a list for concatenating).

Answer (score 1):

the `setdefault` method of dicts come in handy for cases like this:

```
t = (('apple', 'banana'), ('apple', 'carrot'), ('banana', 'carrot'))
d = {}
[d.setdefault(k,[]).append(v) for k,v in t]
```